# How do I check if my DirectShow Renderer filter is being used?

Tags: windows, c++-cli, directshow, multimedia

In my DirectShow project I create a filter (derived from `CBaseVideoRenderer`) to render to a block of memory. This works in most cases perfectly well, with me adding the filter

```
    mGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pInterfaceInfo, MemoryRendererName);
```

and relying on GraphBuilder to do the rest. However in some cases the graph builder and my filter cannot agree on a common format and it creates a new ActiveMovie window, bypassing my filter.

I would like to detect when this occurs so that I know my filter is not being used, but cannot work out how.

I enumerate all filters in my graph, looking for my filter, using the following method:

(EDIT: I pass my my GraphBuilder object as the pGraph parameter when I call this)

```
HRESULT MediaPlayer::CheckFilterGraphFor(IFilterGraph *pGraph, IBaseFilter* pFilterToLookFor)
{
    IEnumFilters *pEnum = NULL;
    IBaseFilter *pFilter;
    ULONG cFetched;

    HRESULT enumeratedFilterCount = 0;

    FILTER_INFO pRefFilterInfo;
    pFilterToLookFor->QueryFilterInfo(&pRefFilterInfo);

    HRESULT hr = pGraph->EnumFilters(&pEnum);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        while(pEnum->Next(1, &pFilter, &cFetched) == S_OK)
        {
            enumeratedFilterCount--;

            FILTER_INFO FilterInfo;
            hr = pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&FilterInfo);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {   
                if(wcscmp(FilterInfo.achName, pRefFilterInfo.achName) == 0)
                {
                    pRefFilterInfo.pGraph->Release();
                    return S_OK;    
                }

                // The FILTER_INFO structure holds a pointer to the Filter Graph
                // Manager, with a reference count that must be released.
                if (FilterInfo.pGraph != NULL)
                {
                    FilterInfo.pGraph->Release();
                }
                pFilter->Release();

            }
        }

        pEnum->Release();
    }

    pRefFilterInfo.pGraph->Release();
    return enumeratedFilterCount;
}
```

But it does not work as expected, as my filter is always found regardless of whether it is in use or not.

**How can I tell when my filter is in use as the video renderer for my DirectShow graph, and when it is not?**

Comment: On your input pin, maybe you can query for whether or not you have a connection with [CBasePin.IsConnected()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368713(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding your renderer filter, find its input pin and check if it's connected or not (IPin::ConnectedTo)

Comment: Thank you - I performed a simple check for the number of pins (since my Renderer should only have one) then used GetPin() and then IsConnected() on the result to test if my renderer was used by GraphBuilder, and it appears to be working very well!